# IndentationError on breaking a line with binary operators as per the PEP8 guidelines

Tags: python, indentation, pep8

I'm trying to indent the following line in Python as per the PEP8 guidelines:

```
temperature_rate = (temperature_values[-1] - temperature_values[0])
                   / (len(temperature_values) * MONITOR_RATE)
```

but I get an `IndentationError` at this line that states "unexpected indent":

```
    / (len(temperature_values) * MONITOR_RATE)
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

I've tried indenting the second line in multiple ways, but they all lead to the same `IndentationError`. Can someone help me in understanding why I'm getting this error here?

Comment: You need to be inside parentheses (or some other type of bracket) to break an expression into multiple lines, or use the line-continuation character, `\`

Comment: What PEP8 guideline you were following in this particular case?

Comment: I was silly to straightaway jump to the "Should a line break before or after a binary operator?" section, without taking a look at the indentation section, which did mention what @juanpa.arrivillaga wrote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to break up long expressions, either use explicit line-continuation character, `\`:

```
temperature_rate = (temperature_values[-1] - temperature_values[0]) \
                   / (len(temperature_values) * MONITOR_RATE)
```

Or, the preferred way, use parenthesis:

```
temperature_rate = ((temperature_values[-1] - temperature_values[0])
                    / (len(temperature_values) * MONITOR_RATE))
```

Note, this works with any bracketed expression, which is why you *could* write a list-literal like:

```
my_list = ['a',
           'b',
           'c']
```